# Minecraft C# Join server afther launching

Tags: c#, minecraft, launcher

Okay I succeeded in creating a custom Minecraft launcher for my server. Everything is working fine but there is one cool thing i would like to add. I think it would be cool if people can instantly join a server upon launching minecraft. Does anyone know if this is possible to do?

Comment: You would need to change the client launcher to always go to the same server. Not something you control from the server.

Comment: sorry i think i didnt explain it well (bad english). I create a client launcher. and i want it to join a specific server upon launching.

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried and what are you having trouble with?

Comment: As i mentioned in my question. "Does anyone know if this is possible to do?" so up until now i didnt even know if its an possibility. cant find any information about this on the web.

Comment: There won't be. It's software owned by Minecraft, you have to mod the launcher, but unless you have the source, that will be tricky.

Comment: I created my own source for the minecraft launcher. i think all i need is a code for joining minecraft servers that i can implant into my launcher code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen:
http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Minecraft_launcher

Specifically the section called

**Command Line usage**

> ```
> MinecraftDev.jar (all systems): java -cp Minecraft.jar net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap <username> <server:port>.
> ```
>
> Beginning with the launcher released with Minecraft 1.6.1, there are
>   other commands for the launcher. These can be seen by running java
>   -jar Minecraft.jar -help.

this shows you it is possible to launch minecraft telling it to connect to server. you should check out the `-help` to see the full list of command line arguments